# ROS Answers SE migration: gscam error

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ;
when i type this command in the terminal """ rosrun gscam gscam"""
the following error appears """" [ERROR] [1399638704.450296280]: Unable to open camera calibration file [../camera_parameters.txt] ,,,, [ERROR] [1399638704.450423311]: No camera_parameters.txt file found.  Use default file if no other is available.
"""
How Can I Solve that ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163116/gscam-error/) by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-05-09**:
Is the """" your error message?

**Comment by [smart engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/15051/smart-engineer/) on 2014-05-09**:
@BennyRe ::
[ERROR] [1399638704.450296280]: Unable to open camera calibration file [../camera_parameters.txt] ,,,,
[ERROR] [1399638704.450423311]: No camera_parameters.txt file found. Use default file if no other is available

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-05-09**:
Is the path to the camera parameters file correct?

**Comment by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) on 2014-05-09**:
Check if you have camera_parameters.txt file in your gscam package directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. gscam need the camera_parameters.txt calibration file in the gscam package directory
2. For it to work well with what you want to do for image processing you should calibrate the camera that you are using
3. camera_calibration package will create the right calibration file for you, which you can place in the gscam package directory

Enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) with karma: 253 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0